# Married surname on flight ticket, maiden name in passport with extra option of new surname

Tags: turkish-airlines, dutch-citizens

My parents will come and visit me in few months time. They will fly with Turkish airlines. My dad booked the tickets with names;

- Albert Jack Harrington (Father)
- Esther Harrington (Mother)

The names are correct as on their (Dutch) passports, but I just realized that on my mother's passport she have her maiden name. Esther Jackson stands in her passport and not Esther Harrington. But I know her new surname is also in the passport through an extra option.

On the Dutch embassy's website, there stands:

> In your Dutch passport you will always keep your maiden name. However,
>   it is possible to have a line added which states: wife/husband of,
>   followed by the name of your wife/husband. To have the name of your
>   wife/husband added to your passport, you will need to submit a
>   (legalized) marriage certificate.

So now I'm really curious. Will it be fine to have her new surname on the flight ticket, or should she still have her maiden name on the ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the airlines have a strict policy on names appearing as per your passport, there are however some exceptions to this e.g. Sri Lankan names are typically too long to go into a booking so the airlines allow pre-agreed abbreviatons.

I would strongly suggest ringing Turkish airlines directly and getting them to confirm whether there are similar considerations for Dutch passport holders.